# Pseudo inverse (SVD) of a singular complex square matrix in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, svd, matrix-inverse, singular

Singular complex matrix is 2<sup>n</sup> x 2<sup>n</sup> where n is 3; 4 or 5. How to calculate Singular Value Decomposition in C/C++?

Input matrix R is in the form Y*Y' where ()' is transjugate.

Eigenvectors in U are the main output. Consider following Matlab code:

```
[U,D,V]=svd(R);
En=U(:,n+1:m); % first few eigenvectors out
EnEn = En*En';
```

Most of the C/C++ libraries (e.g. OpenCV) support matrix inversion and SVD only for real matrices. In the non-singular case

```
R = Re(R) + j*Im(R)
```

resolution helps. Upper half of inverted

```
[Re(R) -Im(R);
Im(R) Re(R)]
```

gives R<sup>-1</sup> when it is complex.
As numerical method is key here, many suggested Armadillo and Eigen instead of implementing a custom error prone solution.

What do you think? Which would be a good choice and why?

Comment: _" in C/C++"_ Such language doesn't exist. Pick one.

Comment: It is up to you. It is an algorithm, not a design pattern.

Comment: Use LAPACK: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html

Comment: Having had to implement SVD in C (and then compile into a Visual C++ application) using a Fortran program as my reference algorithm, it's doable (but this was 15 years ago so I don't remember a whole lot to suggest)  But you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697663/how-to-do-inverse-on-complex-matrix-in-opencv?rq=1 (And I would suggest taking a set of test matrices and comparing what you get in Matlab with whatever solution you use)

Comment: @renonsz then replace both `C` and `C++` tags with the `algorithm` tag.

Comment: use http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svd . there is a support complex matrix

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about numerical methods, not programming.

Comment: @crashmstr No, I am not helped when you give me e. g. Octave code. The platform is C++, but C is also appreciated, it could be integrated without pain.

Comment: @KubaOber I see. And implementing numerical methods is not programming?

Comment: @marc Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: @renonsz and depending on the platform, the C may not work in a C++ compiler because both standards have changed and [C != C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#With_C)

Comment: @crashmstr Yeah, and with this logic C!=C and C++!=C++ because of standards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `A` be a matrix and `A*` its conjugate transpose. Then the matrix `A.A*` is Hermitian. It is even positive semi-definite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose

In this case, there is no fundamental difference between the SVD and the eigenvalue decomposition. http://cims.nyu.edu/~donev/Teaching/NMI-Fall2010/Lecture5.handout.pdf

Hence, the routines of Lapack that can prove useful are [`zheevd()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dae/zheevd_8f.html) and [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f.html).

You can call these function for C thanks to the [Lapacke](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) interface. These functions are wrapped by the libraries [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for C++.

Take a look at this answer of mine for an example of how to call these functions using Lapacke: [low RAM consuming c++ eigen solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268973/low-ram-consuming-c-eigen-solver/32280875#32280875) .